# How to crop and resize Images without chaning the original coordinates

Tags: python, image, numpy, tensorflow

I have bunch of images with it's X and Y Coordinates which are markers for training. I have to resize the images to 500 X 500. Without affecting the original position how to change the size?

I have tried tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad but when I plot the dots using its x and Y to the cropped image it shows wrong coordinates which is left top.

[image: Images with perfect points]
[image: resized and cropped Image]

```
newImage = tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad(
        image,
        500,
        500
    )
```

I want the original Image to be unaffected of it's original coordinates adn have space so when I plot the original points on the image it perfectly fits.

Comment: Is `image` a single image or a batch of them? And what is the format/shape of the markers data?

Comment: batch of images, shape of (97, 270, 312, 3) == (batchsize, size, size, channels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the dots with

```py
x += (500 - image.shape(0)) / 2
y += (500 - image.shape(1)) / 2
```

This should work because the function always crops and pads the image keeping it centered. You might have to check how it works when the original image has an odd size because this would give a float number and it could be half a pixel away from the intended point.

Comment: Just as a comment, this is correct, but one should note that if the width or height of the image is greater than 500 you may get coordinates out of the image (because the marker position was cropped out). But that's just unavoidable really.

Comment: You are absolutely right. A solution could be to throw away the point for which `x<0 or x>500 or y<0 or y>500`, or throw away an entire image when any of the points satisfies the aforementioned condition.

Comment: This is kinda a correct but when you are talking about around 25GB+ of coordinates. This is not applicable. Just moving the images left top is applicable.

Comment: I think that the proposed sum is the fastest solution but you could try something different. For each image, you create a new matrix of zeros and initialize the target coordinates to 1. For example `M = np.zeros(image.shape)` and then for each point you set `M[x, y] = 1`. Then you can apply the same function to `M`, `newM = tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad(M, 500, 500)`. But it's bound to be slower because of the time needed to prepare the matrix.